# Mule Basic Authentication

Tags: mule

I am trying to use Basic authentication and get the credentials in Mule flows.

Here is my Mule flows:

```
<http:listener config-ref="httpConfig" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="get, post, delete" />
<apikit:router config-ref="api-config" doc:name="APIkit Router" />
<flow name="get:/sourcing/helloworld-secure:api-config">
   <flow-ref name="authenticate-ldap" doc:name="authenticate-ldap"/>
</flow> 

<flow name="authenticate-ldap">
    <logger message="Name: #[message.inboundProperties.get('username')] Password:#[message.inboundProperties['password']] level="INFO"/>
    <component class="com.test.AuthTest" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger message="After java: #[flowVars.username] #[flowVars.password]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Map_auth_to_ldap_request" doc:name="Map auth to ldap request"/>      
 </flow>
```

Java code:

```
public class AuthTest implements Callable {
@Override
    public Map<String, String> onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {     
        Map<String, String> authMap = new HashMap<String, String>();              
        final String authorization = eventContext.getMessage().getInboundProperty("authorization");        
        if (authorization != null && authorization.startsWith("Basic")) {           
            String base64Credentials = authorization.substring("Basic".length()).trim();
            String credentials = new String(Base64.decode(base64Credentials), Charset.forName(Base64.PREFERRED_ENCODING));
            if (credentials != null) {
                 final String[] values = credentials.split(":",2);              
                 eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("username", values[0]);
                 eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("password", values[1]);                 
                 authMap.put("username", values[0]);
                 authMap.put("password", values[1]);
            }
        }        
        return authMap;       
    }
}
```

To run this application, I am using rest client in Chrome and selecting Basic Auth, then giving username and password.

Above code is working fine. What I need is instead of getting credentials in Java then put into Map, I need to get the credentials in Mule flows without using Java code. Is this possible in Mule flows directly?

I have implemented with Spring security which is working fine, but in this case I need user to enter credentials and proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing the basic-authentication you can use the "mule-ss:security-manager" element to provide the source of the authentication and  the "http:basic-security-filter" element to establish the restriction. Finally you can get the the credentials in the flow by using the "expresion-transformer" element. Here you have an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
      xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp"
      xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
      xmlns:mule-xml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
      xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
      xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
      xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws"
      xmlns:smtps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps"
      xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
      xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"      
      xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
      xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtps/current/mule-smtps.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.1/mule-spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <spring:beans>      
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
          <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
              <ss:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
              <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON" />
            </ss:user-service>
          </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
      <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9091" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>    
    <flow name="testingFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="Before Authentication" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Failure"/>
        <http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
        <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'Authorization']"/>
        <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String).substring('Basic'.length()).trim()]"/>
        <expression-transformer expression="#[new String(org.mule.util.Base64.decode(payload),java.nio.charset.Charset.forName('UTF-8')).split(':');]" />
        <set-payload value="#[['user':payload[0],'password':payload[1]]]"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="User - Password"/>

    </flow>


</mule>
```

Documentation reference:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-listener-connector#authentication

Comment: as I informed in my question, I am able to do this.

Comment: I have modified the answer to include the way you can get the credentials in the flow. This is not a direct way, but you can do it without creating a java class.

Comment: Mule 3.8.3 is having issue for String split. Use this: <expression-transformer expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(new String(org.mule.util.Base64.decode(payload), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName('UTF-8')), ':')]" doc:name="Expression"/>                                                                                https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/56799/split-statement.html